# neutralinojs workaround to HTML input attribute accept

Tags: neutralinojs

I have a neutralinojs app with an file input. It should only be possible to choose files from type ".csv" or ".xlsx". So I use the accept attribute.

`<input type="file" accept=".csv,.xlsx" />`

That works in browser mode but not in window mode.

Is there a workaround to show only files with these filetypes in the file chooser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Need To Use Neutralino's API For Dialogs.

So In Neutralino's OS API We Have Some Functions For `save file`, `open file` and `open folder` using which we can show dialogs to users.

In your case you need to use `open file` dialog so you can use `Neutralino.os.showOpenDialog`, example:

```js
Neutralino.os.showOpenDialog('Open a file', {
  filters: [
    {name: 'Documents', extensions: ['csv', 'xlsx']},
    {name: 'All files', extensions: ['*']}
  ]
}).then(result => {
  console.log('You have selected:', result);
});
```

One thing to note is all these API will work in both modes, browser and window.

So if you run this code in browser mode a dialog box will still appear.

Read More About [Neutralino's OS APIs](https://neutralino.js.org/docs/api/os)

Comment: Thank you. For another project I already use that method. That works great.